# Posting a numpy array to a dask.distributed.Queue object

Tags: dask

We've noticed that the communication objects like Queue and Variable don't support dask or numpy arrays.

https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Queue

It appears that msgpack doesn't like numpy arrays. Would it make sense to use something like https://github.com/lebedov/msgpack-numpy ?

We are trying to post intermediate results from a loop on a worker back to a Queue. We'd like to consume these results in realtime and plot them in a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Copying documentation from  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives

Queues can also send small pieces of information, anything that is msgpack encodable (ints, strings, bools, lists, dicts, etc.). This can be useful to send back small scores or administrative messages:

```
def func(x):
    try:
       ...
    except Exception as e:
        error_queue.put(str(e))

error_queue = Queue()
```

Queues are mediated by the central scheduler, and so they are not ideal for sending large amounts of data (everything you send will be routed through a central point). They are well suited to move around small bits of metadata, or futures. These futures may point to much larger pieces of data safely:

```
>>> x = ... # my large numpy array

# Don't do this!
>>> q.put(x)

# Do this instead
>>> future = client.scatter(x)
>>> q.put(future)

# Or use futures for metadata
>>> q.put({'status': 'OK', 'stage=': 1234})
```

If you’re looking to move large amounts of data between workers, then you might also want to consider the Pub/Sub system described a few sections below.